# What size of the IT project that should have IT Project Manager?

Tags: organizational-structure

IT PM to be assigned that I mean is 100% IT PM (as a job), not just a role. Could you please share how large or what size of the projects (e.g. project is long more than 3 months ect.) should have IT PM in place?

Answer (score 2):

it will always come down to budget, if you can afford a dedicated PM then don it!

What size dev team? Well with only 3 or 4 devs you can get away with one of them doing the PM role as well but if you have a dedidcated PM, this is where you should start – get the team used to working with a PM and keep the pressure off your devs.

How long? Well the project should at least be worthy of their effort but the PMs job doesn’t start and end with the dev cycle. The PM should be involved from around the time of project commitment from the client, they need to buy in to the delivery cycle and the client needs to know that they are the contact point for the duration of the project.
The PMs role ends after final acceptance from the client – this is normally long after the devs have left (because the testing happens after the devs leave right?)

So, I would say, a full time PM should be involved in any project that runs about three months long (or 1 month of full time dev)

Answer (score 1):

Generally in IT, your PM LOE, which not only includes leadership and oversight but also other PM functions like risk, quality, and communications, is somewhere between 8% to 15% of your total LOE.  I've heard it a bit lower and a bit higher so I adopted this as a general heuristic in IT.

Based on a duration of a year, assuming 1,950 hours as an FTE, I would staff a dedicated PM individual if the project was between 13,000 and 24,300 hours, between 7 and 13 FTEs, or between 8 to 15 individuals (which is consistent with generally accepted guidance for span of control).  For other durations, interpolate accordingly.

This assumes the PM has the competency to cut across all PM functions by himself to the degree necessary for that project.  You run the risk of a PM gap.  Staffing by roles is a safer way to go, generally speaking.

Comment: I've always went by: 50% of a project is development, 15% is Arch/Design, 25% QA and 10% management (which includes PM) - so based on the scope you can derive the amount of PM/Management required

Answer (score 1):

Even small projects can benefit from having project managers.  If the projects are sufficiently small, the PM can work on a number of them in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what the size is, all projects need to be well managed to meet the customer’s needs as  business ethics  as well as for the sake of the company , because any “crack” in relation with the customer may cause some other suppliers to take over the existing/future projects.

- Big sized /Large accounts project  = PM to handle
- Important customers/Big companies = PM to handle, regardless of the size, as outcome of good performance on small projects may open the path to big sized/large accounts projects
- Small /Medium sized/accounts project   = PM handling more than one project as **`Scott`** explained